# Accessing WAMP's localhost from another device via host's IP address stopped working

Tags: iphone, networking, browser, localhost, connect

I've been using a WAMP-server on my laptop to host a website in my parents local wifi network a few days ago. I've always been able to access the localhost-page from other devices which were connected to the same router by typing my laptop's local IPv4-address into the browser.

A few days ago I went back to my students room (where I also have my own wireless-router) and I tried accessing localhost the exact same way as I did before, but it's not working. Here, my local IPv4-address is 192.168.0.107 and I've tried the following to make it work:

- Turn off my laptop's firewall.
- Edit the Apache httpd.conf file from:

  ```
  ...

  Listen 0.0.0.0:80

  ...

  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
  Allow from ::1
  Allow from localhost

  ...
  ```

  to:

  ```
  ...

  Listen 80

  ...

  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from all

  ...
  ```

Yet, whenever I type 192.168.0.107 in the browser of another laptop, it takes forever to load and it eventually tells me that it's taking too long for the server to respond. Please help me!

Note:
I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I've run cmd on another computer (connected to the same router via wifi) and executed the command "ping 192.168.0.107", which seemed to run fine...

**EDIT :**
My httpd.conf file can be found here: http://pastebin.com/h639eFgA.
Also I'm using Windows 7 x64.

**EDIT2 :**
Solved the problem by completely re-installing windows (formatting drives and freshly re-installing). The problem probably had something to do with port 80 of my PC somehow being blocked by my router or some application I think.

Comment: Can you confirm that if you insert the right ip ( 192.168.0.107 ) in the httpd.conf, it is working???

Comment: @Mathlight I'm not sure where to insert my ip in the httpd.conf file as I'm quite new to this. Could you please give me some more information?

Comment: The listen if i'm right...: `Listen 192.168.0.107:80`

Comment: I've just tried changing "Listen 80" to "Listen 192.168.0.107:80" but I still can't access te localserver form other devices by typing 192.168.0.107 in the browser. I also found out that on my laptop (which is hosting the server) I can no longer access the local server-page by typing "localhost" in the browser... only by typing "192.168.0.107"

Comment: That last part is true, because it's only listening on that ip... Are you sure that your DNS settings are set right ( also on the testing machine??? ) try this command: `ipconfig /flushdns`

Comment: Also, did you try in in difrent browsers?

Comment: I've tried both the things you said, but sadly it's still not working... it just keeps loading the local server-page (as if it keeps trying to connect) but eventually fails. Thanks alot for your help so far kind sir, I will be back in a couple of hours...

Comment: Can you post all the content of your `httpd.conf` file? And what OS are you using? XP or win7 or win8?

Comment: @Mathlight I've added a link to the httpd.conf file in my post.

Comment: Alright, if you comment this line: `ServerName localhost` does it then work?

Comment: @Mathlight I've tried what you said and still nothing... Could it possibly be related to using a different router now than the one I was using with my parents?

Comment: Mayby. Do you have an block on port 80 in there? ( or mayby you can enable it somewhere? ). And are you sure you're using the right ip ( not changed without notice? ). And have you tryed to put an `:80` behind the url ( ip of the pc, like this: `192.168.0.107:80` )?

Comment: I'm not sure if port 80 is blocked, it does tell me that it's blocked when I go to: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/. I'm also 100% sure that I'm using the right IP (I check it everytime with the ipconfig command before testing again) and putting :80 behind the local IP didn't help either...

Comment: Try using telnet: [link to walk trough](http://kb.acronis.com/content/7503)

Comment: @Mathlight When I run "telnet 192.168.0.107 80", the command prompt opens a new blank screen. So according to your guide my port 80 is open...

Comment: did you run it on your own PC AND on the testing PC ( the other one??? )

Comment: @Mathlight When I run telnet on my own PC, I get a blank screen, but when I run telnet on the testing PC, it says: "Could not open connection to the host, on port 80: Connection Failed".

Comment: Alright. That means that somewhere port 80 is blocked. It's probably the router. Do you have access to the configuration of it? If so, try to open port 80 somewhere...

Comment: @Mathlight Alright, well then I'll just try to configure my router to get it to open port 80 or I'll borrow my parents' router. You're awesome for helping me the past few days! Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I hope that the problem is fixed very soon ( i know of own experience how frustrating this can be :D )

Comment: Also, if it's not working yet, try [http://superuser.com/](http://superuser.com/) ( also from stackexchange )

Comment: @Mathlight Well I finally got it working.. I was planning on completely re-installing my laptop (formatting hdd's and re-installing windows), also because this wasn't working and it helped. When my pc was all fresh again, all I needed to do was install WAMP and edit the Apache httpd.conf file from "Order Deny, Allow; Deny from all; .....; ......;" to "Order Deny, Allow; Deny from all; Allow from all;". Sadly I still don't know what actually caused this whole thing (probably some application or my router blocking port 80 I think) but it's working now. Thanks for your great support Mathlight!!

Comment: I'm glad that it is working now. Have an happy ( coding ) time ;)

Answer (score 3):

Open your `httpd.conf` file, find "Controls who can get stuff from this server." it is the section that defines which IP address gets access to your Apache server. By default, it only allows access from `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, you need to add the line

```
Allow from all
```

at the end of this section. Now save the file, close it, and restart Wamp. Viola! You'd be able to access Apache server installed on your machine via IP address.
Please mark it as an answer if it solves your question.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: In apache 2.4

change

```
Require local
```

for

```
Require all granted
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html